# IP Redirect using DNS Server

Tags: server, dns, active-directory

For my current project I have an ADDS set up. The ADDS also has a DNS Server installed as a role. The name of my ADDS is corp.nikali.lan. I have to use the DNS Server role to redirect.

The IP address of outlook.com should be reachable by typing email.corp.nikali.lan.

At the moment all I have is the basic set-up after downloading the DNS feature. No added records or anything else.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but do note  at least that "redirect" is an HTTP level feature, not a DNS one, so you shouldn't use this term. The often closest idea is "aliases" also called `CNAME` records.

Answer (score 1):

**CNAME** record - records refer to an alias or redirect for a specific site or subdomain.

Two **CNAME** fields:

- Name
- Destination

Common **CNAME** entries:

Name: www

Destination: @
(or "yourwebsite.com")

Best example :

[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) and fb.com , some people are using a shortcut word like **fb.com** , you need to configure in your (NS) **Name server** , like the example above **CNAME** entries.